# Invalid Credentials Error when tried to access a public data from a dynamo db table

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using an aws-sdk in create-react-app to fetch dynamo DB data as a Guest user. In the Identity Pool, I have an unauthorized role that has limited access to a few tables that is public. When I tried to access data with the code below it shows Invalid credentials. I am new to aws, dynamo DB, I went through the documentation and tried out things. It's not worked as it is a bit different case.Please guide me the right approach to do this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
      credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID
      })
    });

   const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
   const params = {
     TableName: "test_data",
     Key:{ "id":"Test_2020_11_6_18"},
   };

   docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
     } else {
       console.log("Data"+ data)
     }
    });
   }, [])
```

Comment: Have you edited your Cognito Identity Pool, assign an `Unauthenticated Role` and under `Unauthenticated Identities` make sure you have checked `Enable access to unauthenticated identities`?

Answer (score 1):

> I will assume you have deployed the cognito federated identity and set
> the role policy correctly.

I am used to with this approach to work with federated identity :

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION
})
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  'IdentityPoolId': process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID
});
const gp = AWS.config.credentials.getPromise();
gp.then(() => {
  console.log(AWS.config.credentials.identityId)
  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const params = {
    TableName: "test_data",
    Key: { "id": "Test_2020_11_6_18" },
  };

  docClient.get(params).promise().then(data => {
    console.log("Data" + data)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```